# Using regex to replace all spaces NOT in quotes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to replace all spaces that are not included in quotes so something like this:

```
a = 4, b = 2, c = "space here"
```

would return this:

```
a=4,b=2,c="space here"
```

I spent some time searching this site and I found a similar q/a ( [Split a string by spaces -- preserving quoted substrings -- in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79968/split-a-string-by-spaces-in-python#80449) ) that would replace all the spaces inside quotes with a token that could be re-substituted in after wiping all the other spaces...but I was hoping there was a cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 8):

It's worth noting that *any* regular expression solution will fail in cases like the following:

```
a = 4, b = 2, c = "space" here"
```

While it is true that you could construct a regexp to handle the three-quote case specifically, you cannot solve the problem in the general sense.  This is a mathematically provable limitation of simple [DFAs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite-state_machine), of which regexps are a direct representation.  To perform any serious brace/quote matching, you will need the more powerful [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton), usually in the form of a text parser library (ANTLR, Bison, Parsec).

With that said, it sounds like regular expressions should be sufficient for your needs.  Just be aware of the limitations.

Comment: The space between double-quote and 'here' is NOT in quotes in your example.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work:

```
result = string.gsub(/( |(".*?"))/, "\\2")
```

Comment: if you get into single- and double-quoted strings, you need to match opening and closing quote marks

Answer (score 2):

I consider this very clean:

```
mystring.scan(/((".*?")|([^ ]))/).map { |x| x[0] }.join
```

I doubt *gsub* could do any better (assuming you want a pure regex approach).

Answer (score 0):

try this one, string in single/double quoter is also matched (so you need to filter them, if you only need space):

```
/( |("([^"\\]|\\.)*")|('([^'\\]|\\.)*'))/
```