# Run commandline from c# with parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, process

It's possible to run commandline in c# by using something like this :

```
process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = command;
process.Start();
```

The problem is if the command string contains parameters, for example:

```
C:\My Dir\MyFile.exe MyParam1 MyParam2
```

This will not work and I don't see how to extract the parameters from this string and set it on the `process.Arguments` property? The path and filename could be something else, the file does not have to end with `exe`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: So, the question is, how can I split a command line into a `FileName` and `Arguments`.

Comment: Sounds like you want a regular expression to find the break point. Strictly speaking, if the filename contains a space, is should be in double quotes. That would help u a lot. Is this the case, in your example is the filename `C:\\My` or `C:\\My Dir\MyFile.exe`? Incidentally, is that `M` escaped?

Comment: Do the file ends with a dot and any extension? e.g. .com, .exe...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly I would use:

```
string command = @"C:\My Dir\MyFile.exe";
string args = "MyParam1 MyParam2";

Process process = new Process(); 
process.StartInfo.FileName = command; 
process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
process.Start();
```

If you have a complete string that you need to parse I would use the other methods put forward by the others here. If you want to add parameters to the process, use the above.

Comment: And how do I get the results back?

Answer (score 5):

This could be the worst solution, but it could a safer one:

```
string cmd = "C:\\My Dir\\MyFile.exe MyParam1 MyParam2";
System.IO.FileInfo fi = null;
StringBuilder file = new StringBuilder();
// look up until you find an existing file
foreach ( char c in cmd )
{
    file.Append( c );
    fi = new System.IO.FileInfo( file.ToString() );
    if ( fi.Exists ) break;
}

cmd = cmd.Remove( 0, file.Length );
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo( fi.Name, cmd );
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( psi );
```

Comment: thats quite a good idea, it uses the context of the environmnet to infer the correctness of the string. +1 for lateral thinking. Also works if there really are no quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Assertion: If a filename contains a space, it must be wrapped in double quotes.

This is certainly the case in Windows. Otherwise the rules become much more contextual.

Have a look at [regex-matching-spaces-but-not-in-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310473/regex-matching-spaces-but-not-in-strings), I suspect you can use the regex,

```
" +(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"
```

using `Regex.Split()` to convert you command line into an array. The first part should be your filename.