# How to convert more than one iframe to pdf and download it

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, iframe, printing

I have a rozer page where I show other rozer page using 5 iframes. now want to convert these iframes to pdf after loaded full page. how can I do this?

```
    <iframe class="page-inner" src="/ReportFirstPage</iframe>
    <iframe class="page-inner" src="/ReportGenerate"</iframe>
    <iframe class="page-inner" src="/ThirdPage"></iframe>
    <iframe class="page-inner" src="/ForthPage"></iframe>
    <iframe class="page-inner" src="/FifthPage"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its best if you download an external application like wkhtmltopdf and call that in command line. 
Either you can generate a html page and feed that to wkhtmltopdf, or generate the iframes separately and then merge the PDF files with a tool such as ghostscript.

I recommend the following tools:

- https://wkhtmltopdf.org/
- https://www.ghostscript.com/
- Running command line processes from C#: [Run commandline from c# with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964123/run-commandline-from-c-sharp-with-parameters)

Good luck for the project!