# Python: split string by a multi-character delimiter unless inside quotes

Tags: python, regex, string, split, delimiter

In my case the delimiter string is `'   '` (3 consecutive spaces, but the answer should work for any multi-character delimiter), and an edge case text to search in could be this:

```
'Coord="GLOB"AL   Axis=X   Type="Y   ZR"   Color="Gray Dark"   Alt="Q   Z"qz   Loc=End'
```

The solution should return the following strings:

```
Coord="GLOB"AL
Axis=X
Type="Y   ZR"
Color="Gray Dark"
Alt="Q   Z"qz
Loc=End
```

I've looked for regex solutions, evaluating also the inverse problem (**match multi-character delimiter unless inside quotes**), since the `re.split` command of Python 3.4.3 allows to easily split a text by a regex pattern, but I'm not sure there is a regex solution, therefore I'm open also to (efficient) non regex solutions.

I've seen some solution to the inverse problem using lookahead/lookbehind containing regex pattern, but they did not work because Python lookahead/lookbehind (unlike other languages engine) requires fixed-width pattern.

**This question is not a duplicate** of [Regex matching spaces, but not in "strings"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1310473/694360) or similar other questions, because:

1. matching a **single** space outside quotes is different
   from matching a **multi**-character delimiter (in my example the
   delimiter is 3 spaces, but the question is about **any**
   multi-character delimiter);
2. Python regex engine is slightly different from C++ or other
   languages regex engines;
3. matching a delimiter is *side B* of my question, the direct question
   is about splitting a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x='Coord="GLOB"AL   Axis=X   Type="Y   ZR"   Color="Gray Dark"   Alt="Q   Z"qz   Loc=End'
print re.split(r'\s+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)',x)
```

You need to use `lookahead` to see if the `space` it not in between `""`

Output `['Coord="GLOB"AL', 'Axis=X', 'Type="Y   ZR"', 'Color="Gray Dark"', 'Alt="Q   Z"qz', 'Loc=End']`

For a generalized version if you want to `split` on `delimiters` not present inside `""` use

```
re.split(r'delimiter(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)',x)
```

Comment: Great answer thanks! I believe it will deserve many upvotes. I thought it would have raised the `look-behind requires fixed-width pattern` error, but it doesn't: so much the better.