# Splitting arguments -- preserving quoted substrings -- in python

Tags: python, parsing

Exact duplicate: [Split a string by spaces -- preserving quoted substrings -- in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79968/split-a-string-by-spaces-in-python)

---

I want to take in a string and return a list, dictionary or tuple of values as separated by spaces. However, I want to not match spaces that are somehow between quote marks, i.e.

> apple orange "banana tree" green

Should come back as three items, "banana tree" being one whole item.

If possible it should also allow for the escaping of quote marks.

Comment: Renamed both questions to make it obvious that they are exact duplicates.

Comment: The problem is that there are several ways to name such a question, pity I missed the other one.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
def splitstring(string):
    """
    >>> string = 'apple orange "banana tree" green'
    >>> splitstring(string)
    ['apple', 'orange', 'green', '"banana tree"']
    """
    import re
    p = re.compile(r'"[\w ]+"')
    quoted_item = p.search(string).group()
    newstring = p.sub('', string)
    return newstring.split() + [quoted_item]
```

Comment: Fails for some input; try splitstring('apple "foo bar" baz "qux"')

Comment: This not only reorders the items, it also only works for one quoted item.

Answer (score 1):

This problem sounds a lot like parsing tag input, you could take a look at django-tagging [utils.py](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/source/browse/trunk/tagging/utils.py) implementation which solves this kind of problem