# Python: Split a string, respect and preserve quotes

Tags: python, split, shlex

Using python, I want to split the following string:

```
a=foo, b=bar, c="foo, bar", d=false, e="false"
```

This should result in the following list:

```
['a=foo', 'b=bar', 'c="foo, bar"', 'd=false', 'e="false'"']
```

When using shlex in posix-mode and splitting with ", ", the argument for `c`gets treated correctly. However, it removes the quotes. I need them because `false` is not the same as `"false"`, for instance.

My code so far:

```
import shlex

mystring = 'a=foo, b=bar, c="foo, bar", d=false, e="false"'

splitter = shlex.shlex(mystring, posix=True)
splitter.whitespace += ','
splitter.whitespace_split = True
print list(splitter) # ['a=foo', 'b=bar', 'c=foo, bar', 'd=false', 'e=false']
```

Comment: Can there be (escaped) quotes inside quotes?

Comment: Yes, they can (escaped with a backslash).

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/79985/1540600, which provides a superior answer. (Use `shlex.split()`.)

Comment: this is not a duplicate, as `shlex.split` can't specify delimitor.

Comment: I agree with RNA. For using a custom delimiter see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56791723/split-a-string-with-custom-delimiter-respect-and-preserve-quotes-single-or-dou/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
>>> s = r'a=foo, b=bar, c="foo, bar", d=false, e="false", f="foo\", bar"'
>>> re.findall(r'(?:[^\s,"]|"(?:\\.|[^"])*")+', s)
['a=foo', 'b=bar', 'c="foo, bar"', 'd=false', 'e="false"', 'f="foo\\", bar"']
```

1. The regex pattern `"[^"]*"` matches a simple quoted string.
2. `"(?:\\.|[^"])*"` matches a quoted string and skips over escaped quotes because `\\.` consumes two characters: a backslash and any character.
3. `[^\s,"]` matches a non-delimiter.
4. Combining patterns 2 and 3 inside `(?: | )+` matches a sequence of non-delimiters and quoted strings, which is the desired result.

Comment: explain how it works and I'll upvote

Comment: @JasonS I agree, but [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) has a useful explanation section that may help, e.g.: https://i.imgur.com/SJMAQPI.png

Comment: that's useful, but that's not the point, the point is that a good answer explains why it works.

Comment: @JasonS Added some explanation.

Comment: @JanneKarila But this is ignoring the null strings too. How can I retain those?

Comment: Strictly, this answers the question, but beware that escaping the quote character does not work perfectly for the above regex. An input like `a=\"foo, b="bar"` would not be parsed correctly.

Comment: @Zorawar Good remark. The encoder I imagined would escape the quote when it adds the quotes around, so that input would be `a="\"foo", b="bar"`