# How to turn all called function arguments into one (Python 3)

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, arguments, simulator

I am building a terminal simulator in Python, and i have the commands stored in arguments, like:

```
def ls(a):
    for item in os.listdir():
        print item

a = input('Command: ')
a = a.split()
```

The terminal works like this:

1. Ask user for input
2. Splits the input
3. Uses the first part of input to search a function in locals
4. If there is one, uses the rest part of input as argument
5. Calls the function

And i have a problem with cd command.

```
def cd(a):
    if a == None:
        print('cd')
        print('Change directories')
    else:
        os.chdir(os.getcwd() + '/' + a())
```

It works when you make it enter a folder without spaces, like when you type `cd Windows` in the prompt, it works. But the problems start when you try to enter a folder that has spaces in it. When i type, for example, `cd Documents Copy`, it either enters the folder Documents if there is one, or crashes.

How i can fix it? I had a thought about turning all called function arguments into one, but i dont know how to do that, and there might be other ways.

Comment: You might try enclosing arguments with quotes if they contain spaces, like real terminals do.

Comment: But that doesnt work, because it splits the input, like if i will enter cd "Documents Copy", the first part will be cd, second one "Documents, and the third one Copy"

Comment: You may have to do more complex parsing. Creating a terminal is not a trivial task.

Comment: It works until i have to make multiple arguments as one

Comment: Yes, I got that. I suggest reading up on the syntax of some real terminals so you can get a better idea of what wheels you'll need to reinvent for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a more sophisticated `split()` function -- see [Split a string by spaces — preserving quoted substrings answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79968/split-a-string-by-spaces-preserving-quoted-substrings-in-python/79985#79985) for a potential solution.

**UPDATE**

If you had a subdirectory called "the dog" with a space in it, in your interpreter you could do:

```
Command: cd "the dog"
```

The code modifications would be roughly as follows:

```
import shlex
import os

def ls(a):
    for item in os.listdir():
        print(item)

def cd(a):
    if a == None:
        print('cd')
        print('Change directories')
    else:
        os.chdir(os.getcwd() + '/' + a)

a = input('Command: ')
a = shlex.split(a)

if len(a) > 1:
    locals()[a[0]](a[1][:99])
    print()
else:
    locals()[a[0]](None)
    print()
```

Comment: How can i use it in my code?

Comment: @HackerGamerLV, I've added some example usage code & information.

Comment: Hmm...thank you, i will try it!

Comment: Thank you, that was just what i needed.