# python split text by quotes and spaces

Tags: python, split, delimiter

I have the following text

```
text = 'This is "a simple" test'
```

And I need to split it in two ways, first by quotes and then by spaces, resulting in:

```
res = ['This', 'is', '"a simple"', 'test']
```

But with `str.split()` I'm only able to use either quotes or spaces as delimiters. Is there a built in function for multiple delimiters?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html), handy for parsing quoted strings:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> text = 'This is "a simple" test'
>>> shlex.split(text, posix=False)
['This', 'is', '"a simple"', 'test']
```

Doing this in *non-posix* mode prevents the removal of the inner quotes from the split result. `posix` is set to `True` by default:

```
>>> shlex.split(text)
['This', 'is', 'a simple', 'test']
```

If you have multiple lines of this type of text or you're reading from a stream, you can split efficiently (excluding the quotes in the output) using [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

```
import io
import csv

s = io.StringIO(text.decode('utf8')) # in-memory streaming
f = csv.reader(s, delimiter=' ', quotechar='"')
print(list(f))
# [['This', 'is', 'a simple', 'test']]
```

<sub>If on Python 3, you won't need to decode the string to unicode as all strings are already unicode.</sub>

Comment: This is so perfect!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For your case shlex.split will just do fine.

As answer to `multiple delimiters?`

```
import re

re.split('\"|\s', string)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, then you can use regex

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'This is "a simple" test'
```

`>>> re.split('\s|\"', text)`

['This', 'is', '', 'a', 'simple', '', 'test']

Answer (score 0):

using `csv` reader.

```
import csv 
text = 'This is "a simple" test'
list_text=[]
list_text.append(text)
for row in csv.reader(list_text, delimiter=" "):
    print(row)
```

you can also see more about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79968/split-a-string-by-spaces-preserving-quoted-substrings-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

try using   re:

```
import re
text = 'This is "a simple" test'
print(re.split('\"|\s', text))
```

The result:

```
['This', 'is', '', 'a', 'simple', '', 'test']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look into shlex library.

```
from shlex import split
a = 'This is "a simple" text'
split(a)
```

> > ['This', 'is', 'a simple', 'text']

I don't think regex is what you are looking for