# Place a piece of a split on another line in Python?

Tags: string, input, split

I can't find a good example of the following in my textbook:

```
name = (input("Enter name(First Last:"))
last = name.split()
```

From here, I want to input the last name into another string.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string by spaces -- preserving quoted substrings -- in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79968/split-a-string-by-spaces-preserving-quoted-substrings-in-python)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.  Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
full_name = input("Enter name (First Last):")
first_name, last_name = full_name.split()
print(first_name)
print(last_name)
```

Split will return 2 strings here because `full_name` contains only one space between first and last name

Comment: What if i want to print a word in the same situation except without the last character?

Comment: You should use slices in this case: `print(first_name[:-1])` and `print(last_name[:-1])`.

Comment: how do you insert a slice into the middle of a print string, also how do you print an street address without the numbers. all within the same situation?

Answer (score 0):

After looking a little harder I figured out how input a variable into the middle of a string.

Here is the answer for i found for removing numbers from a string and inserting it to another string

```
    <var0> = ''.join([i for i in <var1> if not i.isdigit()])
```

var0 = the string minus the numbers
var1 = the initial string to be changed