# string regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
"GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1"
```

I want the regex in Python which can separate GET, phpmyadmin, HTTP and 1.1 like method, localhost, protocol and version.

Comment: have you tried anything yet? any piece of code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string by spaces -- preserving quoted substrings -- in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79968/split-a-string-by-spaces-preserving-quoted-substrings-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this. Split your string based on the delimiter and extract items to assign to required variables:

```
s = "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1"

method, [localhost, protocol], version = [(x.strip(), y.split(), z) for x, y, z in [s.split('/')]][0]
```

---

More readable way:

```
for x, y, z in [s.split('/')]:
    method = x.strip()
    localhost, protocol = y.split()
    version = z
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work fine, so long as the structure is always the same.

```
s = "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1"
matches = re.match( r'(.*) (.*) (.*)/(.*)', s, re.M|re.I)
ans = list(matches.groups())
```

Reading over regexes would probably be helpful: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm.

Edit: I agree with above, you don't *need* a regex, but it is prettier than the splits and list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with regex, you can split it with `[ /]+`

Python code for same would be,

```
import re
s = 'GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1'
tokens = re.split('[ /]+',s)
print(tokens)
```

This gives following output,

```
['GET', 'phpmyadmin', 'HTTP', '1.1']
```