# How to add a phrase to an array as one element using split?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a string that I turn into an array using split (""). For example:

```
let str = "add 2017-04-25 2 USD Jogurt"
str.split(" ");
["add", "2017-04-25", "2", "USD", "Jogurt"]
```

But how can I add two words to one element to make it like this?

```
add 2017-04-25 3 EUR “French fries”
["add", "2017-04-25", "3", "EUR", "French fries"]
```

I know that it can be use regular expression but how i don't know.
maybe split by "" in this command: add 2017-04-25 3 EUR “French fries”

Comment: there is a simple question[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79968/split-a-string-by-spaces-preserving-quoted-substrings-in-python)

Comment: I need answer on javascript

Comment: Do you want to add two words specifically at the end?

Comment: And do you need an answer without using regular expressions?

Comment: Yes,  specifically at the end and can be with regular expressions

Comment: str.split(); without the quotations?

Comment: if more than one word then use ""

Answer (score 0):

If the provided expression template is mostly static and always looks like "ACTION DATE QUANTITY [CURRENCY_IN_ISO_4217_FORMAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) ITEM_NAME", then regex could be handy:

```
"add 2017-04-25 2 USD Jogurt".replace(/([A-Z]{3}\s)(.*)$/, '$1“French fries”')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try...

```
let str = "add ;2017-04-25 ;3 ;EUR ;French fries";
let reg = /\s*(?:;|$)\s*/;
let strList = str.split(reg);
console.log(strList[4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to use a custom made function instead of regex than here is the code did not test for performance against regex.

input string = 'add 2017-04-25 3 EUR "French crispy fries" and "tasty burger"'

output array = ["add", "2017-04-25", "3", "EUR", "French crispy fries", "and", "tasty burger"]

```
    function myFunction() {
  var str = 'add 2017-04-25 3 EUR "French crispy fries" and "tasty burger"';
  var result = str.split(" ");
  var resultString = [];
  var quotedString = [];
  var ignoreSplit = '"';
  push = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
  {
    //start pushing if you found double quotes on starting
    if(result[i].indexOf(ignoreSplit)==0)
    {
            push = 1;
            //replace double quotes to nothing and push
            quotedString.push(result[i].replace(ignoreSplit,''));
    }
    //push if double quotes found in end
    else if(result[i].indexOf(ignoreSplit)>0)
    {
        //stop the push in between
        push = 0;
        quotedString.push(result[i].replace(ignoreSplit,''));
        //push the quoted string in main result string
        resultString.push(quotedString.join(' '));
        //empty quoted string to be used again
        quotedString = [];
    }
    //push if between the double quotes area
    else if(push == 1)
    {
        quotedString.push(result[i]);   
    }
    //push in the main result string normal case
    else
    {
        resultString.push(result[i]);
    }
  }     
   console.log('final ',resultString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using split, you might also use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to match either from the opening till the closing double quote or match 1+ non whitespace chars using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Use the `/g` global flag to match all occurrences.

```
/(?<=“)[^“”]*(?=”)|[^\s“”]+/g
```

*Explanation*

- `(?<=“)` Positive lookbehind, assert what is direcly to the left is `“`
- `[^“”]*` Match  0+ chars other than `“` or `”` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `(?=”)` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is `”`
- `|` Or
- `[^\s“”]+` Match  0+ chars other than `“` or `”` or a whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B8ZeAV/1)

```js
[
  "add 2017-04-25 2 USD Jogurt",
  "add 2017-04-25 3 EUR “French fries”"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.match(/(?<=“)[^“”]*(?=”)|[^\s“”]+/g)));
```