# How to split a string by spaces excluding ones between double quotes in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, list

I'm trying to split text into a list in Python, but I want to exclude text & spaces between double quotes.
In short, something like this:

```
def splitdq(text):
    # do spliting stuff here...

test = 'The "quick brown fox" jumps over the "lazy dog."'
print(splitdq(test))
>>> ["The", "quick brown fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy dog."]
```

I found some solutions to that, but they either kept the quotes or just didn't work.
So, is there a possible way to do just that in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string by spaces -- preserving quoted substrings -- in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79968/split-a-string-by-spaces-preserving-quoted-substrings-in-python)

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i wanted, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shlex` class which makes it easy to write lexical analyzers for simple syntaxes such as

```
import shlex
test = 'The "quick brown fox" jumps over the "lazy dog."'
s = shlex.split(test)
for i in s:
    print(i)
```

Comment: thanks! that's exactly what i wanted

Comment: you're welcome @bemxio