# How to split a string in python but keep anything in a grouping symbol as one

Tags: python, string

I want to take a string:

```py
x = 'The following is a string: \'Here is a nice python string\'
```

and split it, but keep the inner string intact so it returns:

```py
['The', 'following', 'is', 'a', 'string:', '\'Here is a nice python string \'']
```

This should act the same for `{}` or `[]` or `()`, however, not `<>`.

Comment: isnt that just x.split()

Comment: Yes, but they want to keep the string intact within the single quotes.

Comment: @TruVortex_07 No. For example `'This string \'is nice\'.'.split(' ')` returns `['This', 'string', "'is", "nice'."]`

Comment: No, the desired output would be `['This', 'string', "'is nice'", "."]` Note that the period is separate from the string.

Comment: Check out [Split a string by spaces — preserving quoted substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79968/split-a-string-by-spaces-preserving-quoted-substrings-in-python)

Comment: That doesn't work for {}, [] or ()

Comment: @khelwood does anything in that dupe help with the delimiters other than quotes?

Comment: @MarkM The regex answers do

Comment: @khelwood could you please provide a link to the answer, I'm not sure I know what answer you are talking about.

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524796/3890632) for instance.