# When parsing strings, code is adding string contents and last part of string?

Tags: python, shell

I'm making my own shell in Python and trying to make it as user-friendly and customizable as possible. I'm having an issue when parsing command line strings though.

I have a list of args to be passed to the command.

When I try:

```
echo "Hello World!"
```

My args look like this:

```py
['Hello World!', 'World!"']
```

And not this (desired output):

```py
['Hello World!']
```

The issue isn't an error, just a bug in the code.

Here is my command parser (this should work on its own if you pass something into it):

```py
import os
import imp

from rich.console import Console

def handle_command(console: Console, command: str):
    split_string = command.split(" ")
    command_name = split_string[0]
    command_name = command_name.lower()

    if command_name == "":
        return True

    args = []

    for i in range(1, len(split_string)):
        if split_string[i].startswith('"'):
            res = ""

            pos = i

            while pos <= len(split_string):
                try:
                    res += f"{split_string[pos]} "
                except IndexError:
                    console.print(f"[bold bright_red]ERR: Unterminated string in command arguments[/bold bright_red]")
                    return False
                if split_string[pos].endswith('"'):
                    break
                pos += 1

            if pos == len(split_string):
                if not split_string[pos].endswith('"'):
                    console.print(f"[bold bright_red]ERR: Unterminated string in command arguments[/bold bright_red]")
                    return False

            res = res.replace('"', "")

            args.append(res)
            continue

        args.append(split_string[i])

    commands_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "shells/Fresh/commands")
    
    if os.path.exists(commands_dir) and os.path.isdir(commands_dir):
        for f in os.listdir(commands_dir):
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(commands_dir, f)):
                #try:
                    cmd = imp.load_source(command_name, os.path.join(commands_dir, f))

                    if cmd.name == command_name:
                        if cmd.min_args <= len(args):
                            if cmd.max_args >= len(args):
                                cmd.run(console, args)

                                return True
                            else:
                                console.print(f"[bold bright_red]ERR: {command_name} takes a maximum of {cmd.max_args} arguments[/bold bright_red]")
                                return False
                        else:
                            console.print(f"[bold bright_red]ERR: {command_name} requires atleast {cmd.min_args} argument[/bold bright_red]")
                            return False
                #except Exception as e:
                    #console.print(f"[bold red]ERR: An error occured while running this command[/bold red]")
                    #return False

        console.print(f"[bold bright_red]ERR: Invalid or unkown command '{command_name}'[/bold bright_red]")
        return False
    else:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Commands directory is corrupted or does not exist")
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; "Any help would be appreciated!" is [not how the site works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). We expect a specific, clear question up front, which results from your own best attempt to locate and describe a specific problem. This starts with you carefully checking what the code does, step by step, and figuring out where that diverges from your expectation. After that, *focus* on that part of the code with a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string by spaces -- preserving quoted substrings -- in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79968/split-a-string-by-spaces-preserving-quoted-substrings-in-python)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, find the first point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what you expect & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Your edit does not address the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example,

```
split_string = ["echo", '"Hello', 'World!"']
```

So:

```py
for i in range(1, len(split_string)):
```

will execute it 2 times (one for Hello and one for World)

It will first add `Hello world!` to args than `continue` and this time will add 'World!"' because it doesnt fit the

```py
if split_string[i].startswith('"')
```

I think the problem here is mainly the way the tokens are interpreted. Generally, just splitting a string by spaces is not enough to parse a command correctly when it contains a string

I think you should take a look at what a Lexer is

Comment: Please read [answer] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. Before posting an answer, make sure the question is well posed (this includes it being clear and *specific*; the code should be the minimum required to demonstrate a specific problem, and a question should be asked about it directly), and try to have a more clear idea of the problem than "maybe you should research a specific topic" (that is a red flag that the question is not appropriate).

Comment: Please  use standard spelling & punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting the command with `split_string = command.split(" ")`, so you will get three items `['echo', '"Hello', 'World!"']`.

You iterate starting at index 1 `for i in range(1, len(split_string)):`.

Your code goes through and correctly parses `Hello World!', but the issue is you add this line  `args.append(split_string[i])` after your while loop.

Because of this it will append `'World!"'` to the result, because `if split_string[i].startswith('"'):` will return `False`.

Comment: As with the other answer: please read [answer] - this is not a debugging service and questions like this one should be closed and not answered.

Comment: Because the question is off topic, and answers to off topic questions are not useful and make the site worse.

Comment: He provided actual and expected behavior, as well as provided a reproducible. The OP may not have had the insight to know how to debug the program. I was giving him this insight. I do not see what the problem is. I frankly disagree with you.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions